# jQuery $.post() not sending right information to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm just starting to learn jQuery, php etc.
I have a div (scale) with images with two attributes. I want to write those attributes in a database. As they can change (drag & drop) I want to send all img attributes to the database to update every time a new item is dropped into the div. But instead of sending each child of the div only the current (new added) item is send (multiple times).

jQuery

```
stop: function(event, ui) {
       $('#scale').children().each(function(){
                var idd = $(this).attr("data-id");
                var size2 = parseInt($("#scale > img").length);
                var pos = parseInt($(this).index());
                var rat = 1.00-(1/size2*pos);
                $(this).attr('newRating', rat);

                console.log("We send Movie with ID : " + idd + " on Position: " +pos + " to the DB");

                $.post("userInfo.php",
                {
                    id:idd,
                    rating:rat

                },
                function(data, status){
                    console.log("Data: " + data  + "\nStatus: " + status + " \nof " +  $(ui.item).attr('data-id') + " \nwith " + $(ui.item).attr('newRating') );
                }
                );

            });
}
```

The first console.log gives me the correct ids and ratings, but the data that I get back from the .post() call is wrong.

php

```
        include_once('db.php');

    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $rating =   $_POST['rating'];


    if (mysql_query("INSERT INTO MovieRating SET id = '$id', rating ='$rating' ")){
        echo "Successfully Inserted";
    }
    else{
        echo "Insertion Failed";
}
```

Comment: Please, [don't use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://us1.php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://us1.php.net/mysqli). You will also want to [Prevent SQL Injection!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Have you watched the request / response in the browser's console? You can see what is sent and what is returned.

Comment: Why don't you send all of them as one request instead of bombarding your server with tons of requests?

Comment: Thank you I will look into that. I just checked the request/response. It looks like the correct data is posted. So it's probably a problem in my php?

Comment: UM, I think your log statement is wrong...You are reading the UI and not the item you sent..

Comment: @epascarello because I couldn't find a good way to do it. I did use the jquery sortable .toArray function but that only gives me back one attribute. I'm sorry I'm still very much a beginner to all this. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Nina it sounds like you've checked the *request* (you say the correct data is POSTed). Have you checked the *response* (the data that comes back)? That will tell you whether the PHP is correct or not. What does it return, and what are you expecting it to return?

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log("Data: " + data  + "\nStatus: " + status + " \nof " +  $(ui.item).attr('data-id') + " \nwith " + $(ui.item).attr('newRating') );
                                                                     ^^^^^^^                                   ^^^^^^
```

You are reading ui.item every time you log to the console. You want the item from the current iteration.

```
console.log("Data: " + data  + "\nStatus: " + status + " \nof " +  idd + " \nwith " + rat );
```

Comment: You're right. For some reasons I got undefined earlier. It does work now. Thank you.